# React App Docker deployment Express/PM2 vs Nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, nginx, deployment

i have created and build (react-script build) a simple react application. I want to deploy it to my ubuntu server via a Docker image and i am looking for advise. Is it better to use expressjs and pm2 to serve the react app or would it be more useful to serve it via nginx? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Thanks a lot for your advises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're going to deploy a React application, you've typically used a tool like Webpack to compile it down to a set of static files.  Once you've done that, deploying it via nginx will be smaller and faster than an Express server, and since you don't have the entire Node interpreter involved, there are fewer parts involved to potentially have security issues.

In fact, even if the rest of your application is in containers, it can be beneficial to host the front-end somewhere external (if you're otherwise deploying to AWS, for example, put the built front-end into an S3 bucket).  This can simplify the deployment mechanics a little bit, and with Webpack's file hashing, you can keep older versions of the code for browsers that haven't reloaded the page recently.  You still probably need the nginx proxy (to serve a `/index.html` page, to proxy the back-end services) but you don't necessarily need to redeploy it when the front-end code changes.

The only real advantage to an Express-based deployment setup is being able to live-reload your code in production.  That would come with a high risk of human error, though: make an accidental typo and save the file, and end users see an error page.  I'd avoid this path.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what you mean by hosting the frontend external? How could the frontend contact the backend if they are not on the same server? I assume i would need a public available API endpoint?

Comment: You need a public API endpoint no matter what: the actual frontend code runs in the end user's browser and can't directly communicate with Docker networking.  So once Webpack produces a bundled `.js` file, the only real question is how you serve that file up.  If you had an Express server in the mix, it could serve files to the browser, but the browser is what would be calling the API server, not the Express server.